# What is error code 68 for msmtp and which problems may provoke it?

Tags: email, smtp

Sometimes, when I send mails (from alot MUA making use of `msmtp`) I get the following error message:

> failed to send: msmtp --account=FOO -t failed with code 68:
>   A process has ended with a probable error condition: process ended with exit code 68.

I couldn't find out what exit code 68 refers to nor what the problem ist. Sometimes it works, after I remove everything but the raw email address from "To" (i.e. `Name Surname <surname.name@domain.suffix>` -> `surname.name@domain.suffix`) However there is no pattern visible  in which the problem appears nor are there nay special characters in the address that could create the problem.

What is error code 68 for `msmtp` and how does it relate to the problem described

Comment: From `sysexits.h`: EX_NOHOST (68)    The host specified did not exist.

Comment: thx, though I don't understand than why deleting the realname and the chevrons results in a successfully sent email. The host is still the same afterwards.